# Why Swift global functions as a special case of closures capture global variables?

Tags: ios, swift, closures

According to The [Apple Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94): Global functions are closures that have a name and **do not** capture any values. But I ran into an example domenstrating use of closures in the book *IOS 11 Programming Fundamentals with Swift*, which passes a **global** function A as a parameter into another global function B to modify the value of a global variable x. The book states that A captures X, which contradicts what the Swift documentation says.

The code example:

```
func pass100(_ f: (Int) -> ()) {
    f(100)
}

var x = 0
print(x) // output 0

func setX(newX: Int) {
     x = newX
}

pass100(setX)
print(x) //output 100
```

The above code snippet works in Xcode and I am confused. Could anyone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID103) is what "capturing" means:

> A closure can capture constants and variables from the surrounding context in which it is defined. The closure can then refer to and modify the values of those constants and variables from within its body, **even if the original scope that defined the constants and variables no longer exists.**

Global functions are said to not capture anything because you can never leave the global scope while your program is running, so there is no point in capturing anything. If it did capture something, that means global variables can still be changed even after you somehow "left" the global scope (maybe the program finishes running), which would be weird.

The global function in your code is not capturing anything. It can change the value of `x` simply because `x` is still in scope. You've not left the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

> A closure can capture constants and variables from the surrounding
>   context in which it is defined.

Global, like local, is a context. `A` is a global function and `X` is a global variable; therefore, `A` captures `X`. Technically, all of the methods in the app capture `X` because it's exposed in the global context. Conventionally speaking, however, "capture" usually refers to a local scope.

To demonstrate this, if you moved `A` and `X` into a local scope, such as a method within a class, nothing changes—`A` still captures `X`. All you've done in your example is placed them into a global scope, and because they're in the same scope (or context), the rules of capturing have not changed.

It's a matter of semantics and convention and I would argue that this is one area where Swift documentation may be slightly misleading (if I were Apple, I'd reword it). Moving a function from a local scope to a global scope in no way alters its ability to capture. I think what Apple means is that by default, a local method always captures something (even if it's `self`), whereas a global function is not guaranteed to capture anything if there isn't anything around to be captured.